# making handleRequest an async method on passportjs guard

Tags: typescript, nestjs

```
@Injectable()
export class RefreshAuthGuard extends JwtAuthGuard {
    constructor(
        private readonly jwtService: JwtService,
    ) {
        super();
    }
    public handleRequest(err: any, user: any, info: Error, ctx: any): any {
        if (err || !user) {
            if (info.name === 'TokenExpiredError') {
                const request: Request = ctx.getRequest();
                const headers: IHttpRequestHeaders = request.headers as IHttpRequestHeaders;
                const refresh_token = headers.refresh_token;
                if (!this.isValidRefreshToken(refresh_token)) {
                    throw new HttpException('Invalid refresh token', HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
                }
            } else {
                throw new HttpException('Unauthorized', HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
            }
        } else {
            throw new HttpException('Expired tokens only', HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
        }
    }

    private isValidRefreshToken(refresh_token: string): boolean {
        return !!refresh_token;
    }
}
```

***Problem:***

If I add `async` to the method and make it return `Promise<any>` for now it says:

```
Property 'handleRequest' in type 'RefreshAuthGuard' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'JwtAuthGuard'.Type '(err: any, user: any, info: Error, ctx: any) => Promise<any>' is not assignable to type '<TUser = any>(err: any, user: any, info: any, context: any, status?: any) => TUser'. Type 'Promise<any>' is not assignable to type 'TUser'
```

I really need these methods to be async so that I could retrieve user's refresh_token from the DB and validate it inside this guard. I need these operations async.

EDIT:

this piece is from the nestjs source code:

```
export declare type IAuthGuard = CanActivate & {
    logIn<TRequest extends {
        logIn: Function;
    } = any>(request: TRequest): Promise<void>;
    handleRequest<TUser = any>(err: any, user: any, info: any, context: any, status?: any): TUser;
};
export declare const AuthGuard: (type?: string | string[]) => Type<IAuthGuard>;
```

So it looks that the method can't be asynchronous...

Comment: What happens if you do `async handleRequest<Promise<any>>(err: any, user: any, info: any): Promise<any>`?

Comment: let me check it

Comment: @JayMcDoniel everything gets broken, it looks terrible...it throws a bunch of errors: `'any' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`, `Cannot find name 'user'`,  `Missing semicolon` etc

Comment: Yep, went in to look at the source code, I don't think you can make this async (though you can still do it with promises, but the asynchronicity may throw some things off)

Comment: @JayMcDoniel yeah seems so, well I think a better alternative would be to move that validation logic somewhere else...even though I'm still not sure where...

Answer (score 4):

I realize this an old question, however, you need to do this in your `jwt strategy` which extends the default PassportStrategy and can offer your own custom `validate` method, which can be asynchronous...

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService
  ) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKey: jwtConstants.jwt_token_secret,
    });
  }

  async validate(payload: any) {
    const user = await this.authService.validateUserFromUsername(payload.username);
    if (!user) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
    return user;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add ts-ignore command above your **handleRequest** function and make it an **async** function like bellow:

```
// @ts-ignore: Unreachable code error
   async handleRequest(err, user, info: Error, context: ExecutionContext) {
       // Your code
   }
```